# DPC Latency Issue Caused by Realtek Controller Driver

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, drivers, performance

There is a [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/813628/stuttering-latencies-when-lan-ethernet-driver-active) very similar to my issue but it has not been answered.

Some time after I re-installed Windows 8.1 on my Asus X551CA the sound would stutter regardless of whether it was an online stream of audio or a mp3 on my hard drive. It would go away for a while if I rebooted but it will come back after a couple of hours.

It will stutter mostly when there is a quick change in the pitch of the audio stream and other random times. There are times when it won't stutter at all and other times when it stutters for a while.

I downloaded a DPC Latency Checker and I noticed that when I disabled the **Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller** from Device Manager the latency would disappear and audio worked perfectly...however that driver is responsible for my internet connection so I can't just leave it disabled.

I tried rolling back the driver to the one from 2013 but that didn't help. I downloaded the most recent version also and installed it from the Realtek site but the problem persists.

How can I fix this latency issue and still have internet connection capabilities?

Comment: use USB 3.0 LAN Adapter with other chipset

Comment: @magicandre1981 Well I would really like to fix the issue not just avoid it...the card worked fine before...I want to try to find out what I can change to get it working again.

Comment: try different  driver versions until you find a working one. this is a driver issue

Comment: Try to delete the Realtek device in Device Manager and reboot, to let Windows install a clean driver version. Are you using the driver from [October 2, 2017](https://realtek-download.com/realtek-pcie-fe-family-controller/)? You could also consider upgrading to Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc I will try that tonight, thank you. I want to keep Windows 8.1 though.

Comment: Tonight was 5 nights ago.

Comment: @harrymc Apologies for not getting back...I tried it that night but I needed to wait a while before I knew if it worked or not and I didn't have to time to get back after that... I tried deleting the driver and when I rebooted it installed the 3/23/2017 driver. Unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried instaling the latest driver and that did not work either. Apologies again for taking so long to get back

Comment: By didn't work I mean I had the same latency issues.

Comment: After you installed the latest driver, did you try again to delete the device?

Comment: @harrymc yes and it reverts back to the older 3/23 driver.

Comment: Weird. Suggestions: (1) If windows is updating the driver by itself then block it as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672), (2) If the driver is not well installed, do it manually by unzipping the package and [manually update the driver](https://www.lifewire.com/updating-drivers-in-windows-7-tutorial-2619224) where you browse down to the folder where your exact driver is found, for example `C:\Temp\0034-Install_Win8_8.1_8058_09202017\Install_Win8_8.1_8058_09202017\WIN8\64`.